# How to initialize an NSTimer in the AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to initialize an `NSTimer` in swift in the `AppDelegate`. I'm trying to start a timer once a user exit's a beacon monitoring region like so.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {

        manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as! CLBeaconRegion)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        NSLog("You exited the region")
        sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("You exited the region", playSound: true)
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("yourFunction"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```